# I am getting /create_seeker/?complete_list=true but I need /create_seeker?complete_list=true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Here is the following Code. I have used axios with react.

```js
axios.get(`https://resolab-backend.herokuapp.com/core/create_seeker`,{
params:{
    complete_list : true
},
headers:{
    'Authorization': `Token ${cookies.get("token")}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your query param in URL using template string as shown in below code:

```
const complete_list = true
axios.get(`https://resolab-backend.herokuapp.com/core/create_seeker?complete_list=${complete_list}`,
headers:{
    'Authorization': `Token ${cookies.get("token")}`
})
```